# How can we change foreground of dayitem (1,2,3..) of calendarview?

Tags: calendarview

I have tried using the calendarviewdayitemchanging event , args.item.foreground=green But this is not working.

Comment: Do you need to change all day numbers to a single color? Is this WinUI 3? or UWP?

Comment: For Winui 3 only , I need to change only the particular date  number  to single color(only have to change the foreground not the background)

Comment: By "particular", you mean that you need to pass a list of dates to ``CalendarView`` and change the colors of those dates in the list?

Comment: Yeah, I have to change only the saturday date number to single color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

```xml
<CalendarView CalendarViewDayItemChanging="CalendarView_CalendarViewDayItemChanging" />
```

```cs
private void CalendarView_CalendarViewDayItemChanging(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Item.Date.DayOfWeek is DayOfWeek.Saturday &&
        GetTextBlock(args.Item) is TextBlock saturdayTextBlock)
    {
        saturdayTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SkyBlue);
    }
}

private TextBlock? GetTextBlock(CalendarViewDayItem calendarViewDayItem)
{
    int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(calendarViewDayItem);

    for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
    {
        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(calendarViewDayItem, i) is TextBlock textBlock)
        {
            return textBlock;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

PS: You also can use [Framework Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/frameworkelementextensions) from the **CommunityToolkit** instead of GetTextBlock().

Comment: You r Awesome!!This works perfectly .